# Can Heroes continue to use their upgrades once they've run out of Hero days?

Tags: die2nite

Some people in my town have been asking this, and I'm not 100% sure.

Here's an example, in case my title wasn't clear enough:
Say a Hero builds a Kitchen in his home, that can be used to convert food into better dishes that give more ap.  If this Hero's hero days run out, will he still be able to use the already-built kitchen to continue converting food?

Comment: Seems we have some conflicting answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have seen, Hero upgrades that require an action stop working, but passive upgrades stay active.

This means you cannot use

1. Kitchen
2. Home Laboratory
3. Siesta Time™

But the following stay active

1. Fence
2. Large Curtain
3. Lock
4. Reinforcements
5. More storage

And I believe that the Rudimentary Alarm will keep working, but I have never seen anyone with it.

Comment: Another ex hero in our town has confirmed he still has 6 storage slots from the more storage upgrades

Answer (score 2):

I believe badp is correct, but it should also be mentioned that if you later add more hero days (while in the same town), you can then start using the things you had built earlier again.  So they aren't exactly wasted, just dormant.  I'm not sure about the defense bonuses though.  I believe they still apply during the attack on your last hero day, but they may disappear after that.